# Using an array formula to filter a range of data row by row

Tags: excel

I have the formula `=IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(XMATCH($D$23,3:3))),$A3,"")` that I want to use to filter a list (single column range) of items in column A based on data to the right of column A. The location $D$23 is arbitrary but would be fixed. This formula works fine to filter the list if I copy-paste down a column. Because the list to be filtered is dynamic, I cannot know how far down to paste the formula. I would ideally like to convert this plain formula into an array formula that would take the source list as an argument and apply the conditional on each row of the source list, returning an array. I am not interested in VBA solutions as the entire project is based around getting rid of VBA/macros.

Answer (score 0):

Use FILTER:

```
=FILTER($A3:$A1040000,NOT(ISNUMBER(--INDEX($B$3:$Z$1040000,0,MATCH($D$23,$B$3:$Z$3,0)))))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that with dynamic ranges rather than just searching to the max row every time?

Comment: that is why I put `1040000` if you have more that 1.04 million items, it is time to change to a database.

Comment: Of course. I meant that I am likely to need only to look through dozens not thousands of rows. I suppose I could just pick a substantially large number that we are unlikely exceed, but I would ideally like to define a dynamic range that would fit this formula.

Comment: Use a structured table then and use structured references.